# Why does the while keep looping here? Can somebody explain?

Tags: python

I have the below code to generate fibonacci series upto 'num'

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    while b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num,a,b)
fibo(30)
```

And below is the Output. However if i use 'if' instead of 'while' in my code it works fine. But I wanted to know what is the problem with while here..

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
2
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
2
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
3
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
5
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
8
13
21
21
13
21
21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling a `loop` and also a recursion on `fibo` function. You need to use just one, so that this function with `if` and `recursion`:

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    if b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num,a,b)
```

Is equals to this function with `while` and **without** `recursion`:

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    while b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
```

Basically if you leave them both you will call the `fibo` function at every cycle inside the loop, and every call creates a new cycle in which it will be called again and again.

### Important note

It's better in Python to use iterative functions instead of recursive. This is because Python **DOES NOT** optimize [`tail-recursion`](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion *on top of* your while-loop. Either do it like this:

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    if b <= num:  #Version with recursion
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num,a,b)
```

Or like this:

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1): #Version without recursion but with a while-loop
    while b <= num:  
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
b = 1
a = 0
def fibo(num):
    global a, b
    while b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num)
fibo(30)
```

This will give the output as below.

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
```

Is this the expected output?

Comment: Global variables are usually a bad idea (there they are too). Because nothing prevents a programmer from writing e.g. `a = 4` (even in another file) and then calling `fibo(30)`, which unsuprisingly gives wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing call by value. Just remove the recursive function call and try running again

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes i've tried that. Also I tried this and it works.
'code'
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    if b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num,a,b)
'code'
Wanted to know y it doesn't work in case of while and recursion

Comment: In your case, you are calling the recursive function first and then after it finishes its job while loop continues its job. Since the recursion here is a pass by the value you won't get the expected output. If you still not able to understand try to use python visualizer for better understanding of this concept:

here is the link for python visualizer: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 0):

2 possibles implementations are:

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    while b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b

fibo(30)
```

or:

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    if b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num,a,b)
fibo(30)
```

In the second one, you use recursivity with a breaking condition to stop the iteration, thus the `if condition` to stop the program. In the first one, the program loops until it reached the condition. There is no need for recursivity (calling fibo again).

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    while b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b       
fibo(30)
```

because you are using recursive function and calling function again and again

Answer (score 0):

You mix recursive and iterative approach in the code, so either try a version with iteration and no recursion:

```py
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    while b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
fibo(30)
```

or use recursion and no iteration (i.e. execute the assignment only once, not in a loop):

```
def fibo(num,a=0,b=1):
    if b <= num:
        print(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        fibo(num,a,b)
fibo(30)
```